# Can CssLayout be used to achieve absolute positioning of components?

Tags: vaadin

Currently I am using AbsoluteLayout, but because of some problems I would like to give CssLayout a try.

I would like to dynamically place image-, label- and button-components at specific positions in the layout.

AbsoluteLayout allows me to specify the position like so:

```
absoluteLayout.addComponent(component, "top:20px;left:20px")
```

Is something like this at all possible to achieve with CssLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply inline CSS for a component by overriding `getCss` on CssLayout, so the following should have the wanted result:

```
  CssLayout cssLayout = new CssLayout() {
    @Override
    protected String getCss(Component component) {
        // check the component here and return correct css. In this case only one component in the layout so this works..
        return "position: relative; top: 10px; left: 10px";
    }  
  };
  cssLayout.setSizeFull();

  cssLayout.addComponent(new Button("Hello"));
```

Comment: Yes :-). I also figured that out yesterday, it works great! Just didn't have time to write an answer about it, so thanks! Specifically I saved each component's css (position) at creation time via the setData() method. Then I just get that in the getCss() method and return it. I'm quite happy with this solution, I have to say.